# Uploaded file gets lost when the model is passed inside RedirectToAction method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, file-upload

This is the action method where I save user input and then redirect to the view mode:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveDocumentCitizen(DocumentCitizen documentCitizen)
{
    DocumentCitizenRepository repository = new DocumentCitizenRepository();
    repository.SaveDocument(documentCitizen);
    return RedirectToAction(actionName: "ViewDocumentCitizen", routeValues: new RouteValueDictionary(documentCitizen));
}
```

And here's the ViewDocumentCitizen action method:

```
public ActionResult ViewDocumentCitizen(DocumentCitizen doc)// The Attachment value is null here
{
    DocumentCitizenRepository repository = new DocumentCitizenRepository();
    DocumentCitizen docCitizen = repository.UpdateTextualValues(doc.DocID);
    return View(viewName: "DocumentCitizen", model: docCitizen);
}
```

The DocumentCitizen model has the following property:

```
public byte[] Attachment{get;set;}
```

I choose a file then submit the form and then when I debug the `SaveDocumentCitizen` method I can see that the Attachment is not null. But it gets set to null as soon as it's passed to the `ViewDocumentCitizen` method. What do I have to do to have the file property value persisted through redirection?

Comment: try to use httppostedfilebase instead...

Comment: I've extended ByteArrayModelBinder to convert HttpPostedFileBase to byte[]. Please see this linkn to see how.http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/6/model_binding_posted_file_to_byte_array

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is parameter name in RouteData and in Action method are not equal . Try to modify your `SaveDocumentCitizen` action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveDocumentCitizen(DocumentCitizen documentCitizen)
{
    DocumentCitizenRepository repository = new DocumentCitizenRepository();
    repository.SaveDocument(documentCitizen);
    return RedirectToAction(actionName: "ViewDocumentCitizen", routeValues: new RouteValueDictionary(new RouteValueDictionary(new Dictionary<string, object> {{"doc", documentCitizen}})));
}
```

Or better

```
return RedirectToAction(actionName: "ViewDocumentCitizen", routeValues: new { doc = documentCitizen});
```

This should help to your ModelBinder to recognize parameter by name

**EDIT:**

From MSDN "Controller.RedirectToAction "

> Returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser to make a GET request to the specified action.

**Get** method has a length limit, read more [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659995/2115584)

But .Net Framework ready for everything, and they created ControllerBase.TempData property read more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata(v=vs.118).aspx)

Hope it will help you

Comment: That way the parameter itself becomes null.

Comment: The RedirectToAction send a [GET] request, maybe your byte array too big for it? if it's so, then use TempData storage it's created for this